# method Array.push() javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to add a new item to array or change the item by id, but When I call the method push, it just creates a new item with a key 0,1,2...

I wrote this array

```
var finalArray = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    id=123;
    writeArray(id, "Jason");
    //When I click the button, array always create a new item instead of change the item by id (123).
});

function writeArray(id, name){
var array = {
    [id]:{
    name: name
    }
};
finalArray.push(array);
}
```

In result, array always creates a new item which is showing below. But I need to change the item by id.

```
0:{
    123: {
       name: "Chinga"
    }
}

1:{
    123: {
       name: "Chinga"
    }
}

2:{
    123: {
       name: "Chinga"
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: `var array = {` <-- that ain't an array

Comment: `Array.push()` always adds element to array, you can't modify element of array with this method

Comment: The `push` method is used to add one or more elements to the end of an array which is well documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I call the method push, it just creates a new item with a key
>   0,1,2...

`push` will always add a new item, you need to first check if the item already exists.

```
function writeArray(id, name){

    var index = finalArray.findIndex( function(item, index){
       return Object.keys( item )[0] == id;
    });

    //existing logic
    var array = {
      [id]:{
          name: name
      }
    };
    if ( index == -1 )
    {
       finalArray.push(array);
    }
    else
    {
       finalArray[index] = array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently push an object in an array everytime you call your `writeArray` method, which is not the objective.
As you want to edit an object, using it as a map pretty much, you should access the key (id) you want directly and set the desired value.

```
finalArray[id] = name;
```

Comment: I don't think this is right answer. You just replaced an object with a `name` variable content.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not an array, but an object.

```
// Initialize object.
var finalObject = {}; /* Changed [] to {} */

function writeToObject(id, name){
  finalObject[id] = name;
};
```

If you still want to use an array, just write `finalArray[id] = name` but if you got 123 as a number (read: index), that will automatically create empty spaces up to index 123.

Comment: In this case there is no need to wrap this into a function `writeToObject`

Comment: I'm guessing there are several buttons, and it's IMHO a better standard to break code into smaller functions. The book Clean Code agrees with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two approaches you can use here:

Instead of an `array` you can just use an `object` which simplifies the code pretty much:

```
finalObject = {};
finalObject[id] = name;

// Structure
finalObject = {'123': 'Jason', '1234': 'John'}
```

However, if you have to use an actual `array`, the solution would be to iterate through the array and check if an object with the given ID already exists and if so then modify the name property of it other case just push a new object to the array.

```
// Structure
finalArray = [{id: '123', 'Jason'}, {id: '1234', 'John'}]
```

Both could be valid solutions depending on your use case.